# Primary id not found in FMDB

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). I have execute the following code

```
FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"select * from customer"];
while([results next]) 
{   
    Customer *customer = [[Customer alloc] init];

    customer.customerId = [results intForColumn:@"id"];
    customer.firstName = [results stringForColumn:@"firstname"];
    customer.lastName = [results stringForColumn:@"lastname"];

    [customers addObject:customer];
    NSLog(@"%d",  customer.customerId);
}
```

But I am not getting the customerId value. I just want the rowid which is incremented automatically.

Kindly suggest something...

Comment: What is the structure of your "customer" table?

Comment: Is there any field with name `id` in your table?

Comment: No.. There is no field of id. It has only firstname and lastname. But I want the rowid which is automatically created and automatically incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column with field name `id` of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. While inserting a row, you don't need to insert any value for this field.

[More info](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

And, Just FYI, `release` the `customer` object to avoid memory-leak.

```
[customers addObject:customer];
NSLog(@"%d",  customer.customerId);
[customer release];
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, then it would be great if you accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using intForColumnIndex:0 instead of intForColumn?